# res.json() won't work when trying to display data

Tags: express

I am using Nodejs, express, and postgresql to create a rest api. This is my first time doing any of this so I apologize for the noobness. I have been just testing this out and seemed to be about to get retrieve information from a database locally but when I try to send the data with res.json() nothing shows up. Here is the code I have so far.

```
var express = require('express');

var client = new pg.Client({user: 'xxx', password: 'xxx', database: 'xxx', host: 'xxx'});

var app = express();

app.get('/test1', function(req,res){
   var name;
   client.connect(function(err){
       if(err){
          return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
       }
       client.query("select classname from class", function(err, result){
           if(err){
               return console.error('error running query', err);
           }
           name = result.rows[0].classname;
           console.log(name);
           client.end();
    });
    });
    res.send(name);
});
```

I used the console log and it printed out what I needed but for some strange reason it won't send. Thanks for the help! Also, if you see anything else wrong don't be afraid to say it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an asynchronous function so it would go like this:

```
var express = require('express');

var client = new pg.Client({
  user: 'xxx',
  password: 'xxx',
  database: 'xxx',
  host: 'xxx'
});

var app = express();

app.get('/test1', function(req, res) {
  var name;
  client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
    }
    client.query("select classname from class", function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
      }
      name = result.rows[0].classname;
      console.log(name);
      client.end();
      res.send(name);
    });
  });

});
```

What is happening in your code is that you are sending before the query is done executing. You can see it on the console because your log statement is correctly executing after the query.

Also you should take care of your errors as well - so instead of returning do another res.send (or res.json) with some error mesg.